# Obtain system window count with .net core

Tags: .net-core

I knew how to do this in .net , but in the core framework can it be done.
How do find the count of open windows (any application) on the desktop.
Can I still pinvoke the result?

Comment: How about getting it from `Process` like `Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.MainWindowTitle)).Count();`

Comment: That sounds like a good solution to me. Indeed in this instance, I'm actually looking for something from a specific process; so this is ideal I guess.